# How Pass Schema Name as Parameter in Telerik Reporting Designer

Tags: sql, telerik-reporting

I am trying to pass Schema Name as Report Parameters While Writing SQL Query in "Telerik Reporting Designer Configure Data Source Command Window".

The Orignal Query is this (its working fine in Command Windows)

```
SELECT
[8f2175c0-7021-4286-86ec-f2dd627fdc73].[QuizActivity].[ID], 
[8f2175c0-7021-4286-86ec-f2dd627fdc73].[QuizActivity].[RowID]
FROM [8f2175c0-7021-4286-86ec-f2dd627fdc73].[QuizActivity]
```

But If I write this query to get result based on Schema Parameter, I received an error

```
SELECT
@SchemaName.[QuizActivity].[ID], 
@SchemaName.[QuizActivity].[RowID]
FROM @SchemaName.[QuizActivity]
```

**Incorrect Syntax near QuizActivity**

my default value is [8f2175c0-7021-4286-86ec-f2dd627fdc73]

[image: Screenshot of Configure Data-source Command Window]

[image: Reporting Designer Parameter Configuration]

What should I do resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to escape the value:
`="\[8f2175c0-7021-4286-86ec-f2dd627fdc73\]"`

Reference:
https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/expressions-global-objects